# Firebird - update row's value in table basing on some condition

Tags: firebird, sql-update

As far as I remember I could do such update in MS SQL Server:

```
UPDATE MyTable SET MyValue = (IF SomeCondition THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

or different way for update by using CASE:

```
UPDATE MyTable  SET MyValue  = (CASE WHEN SomeCondition1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

Is any of this methods possible in Firebird? I've tried both ways but with no luck.

Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Which version of FireBird are you using? I tested with 2.5 and the second one (using `CASE`) works as expected.

FireBird doesn't support `IF` statement in DSQL but you can use `IIF` internal function, ie following works too:

```
UPDATE MyTable SET MyValue = iif(SomeCondition, 1, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip with IFF, indeed the second statement is working now also. It seems I've made some mistake testing the query and wrote a correct version here.